# How to get in Isolation Mode from Layers panel in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers, illustration

The most known way to get into Isolation Mode in Adobe Illustrator is by double-clicking on the image.

Nonetheless, is there a way I can get into this mode from the Layers panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Layers Panel has a menu item "Enter Isolation Mode".

Other than that, there is no direct way via the Layers Panel.

Comment: Oh, it's in the panel's menu. Now I got it. Thanks!